# Can't JSON parse a string that contains leading zeros.

Tags: json, string, parsing

When I pass this string to JSON.parse it doesn't work, but if I remove the leading zeros on "000634" it does. Does anyone know why this is? Thanks in advance.

**This does not work:**

```
    var str = '[["first", "last", "XU10060282", "Dept", 000634, "Position", 156689]]';
    var dataArray = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(dataArray);
```

**This does work:**

```
    var str = '[["first", "last", "XU10060282", "Dept", 1000634, "Position", 156689]]';
    var dataArray = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(dataArray);
```

`

Comment: Technically, 000634 in your example is a number, not a string. But that is odd - I just verified it myself in Safari. I get a "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Expected ']'" message in the error console.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to treat it as the number 634, wrapping the value in quotes also works:

```
var str = '[["first", "last", "XU10060282", "Dept", "000634", "Position", 156689]]';
```

Comment: Interesting... I might try to removing the zeros with a regex too.